# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} show different data

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-referer

Why RewriteCond  dont work?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^page([0-9]+).html$ index.php?page=$1

RewriteRule ^p([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_]+).html$ index.php?id_post=$1&title_post=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/page([0-9]+).html$ index.php?mpoint=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+).html$ index.php?mpoint=$1
RewriteRule ^.*.html$ index.php?mpoint=$1


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^www.example111.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^example222.ml$ 
RewriteRule .* – [F]
```

index.php

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

result: `http://www.example111.com/xxxx/yyy.html`

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the `$` in your `RewriteCond` pattern. It anchors the match to the end. Therefore

```
^example222.ml$
```

will match the exact string `example222.ml` which is not the case here. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(www\.)?example111\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ – [F]
```

Comment: @user3572969 These directives should also go near the top of your .htaccess file, before your other rewrites.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this variant. Still dont work.
Maybe rewriteBase doing problem?

Comment: @user3572969 hmm. That is weird. Is `example111.com` not your own domain?

Comment: example111.com is not my